# Yii2 Model подзапрос в запросе

Tags: yii2, запрос, model

Вопрос: как правильно организовать в yii2 запрос с подзапросом на базе методов модели.

Текущий вариант метода модели:

```
class Some extends Model
{
 public static function getUserItems( $user_id )
    {
        // ID всех Some_id привязанных к пользователю ( таблица item_result ) [в ней связь многие к одному]
        $ids = Item_result::find()
            ->select(['some_id'])
            ->where(['user_id' => $user_id])
            ->createCommand()
            ->queryColumn();  
        // тут выбираются все данные SOME по всем $ids + та Some где user_id = $user_id  
        $resp = self::find()->where(['user_id' => $user_id]);
        if ( count($ids) ) $resp = $resp->orWhere(['in', 'some_id', $ids]);
        $resp = $resp->all();  
        return $resp;
    }
}
```

Уверен что есть более оптимальный вариант... но не могу вспомнить/найти...
сойдёт даже custom SQL вставить в orWhere

Кто подскажет ссылкой или примером?

Comment: А стандартные реляции чем не угодили? Там можно и один к одному, и один ко многим, и через связующую таблицу. Вот тут можно и почитать. https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-db-active-record.html#relational-data

Answer (score 2):

Нужна отдельная таблица для хранения подобных связей, и реализовать ее лучше будет в классе User, унаследованного от ActiveRecord.

```
class User extends ActiveRecord
{
 public function getUserItems()
    {
        $this->hasMany(Items::className(), ['id' => 'itemId'])
             ->viaTable(UserItems::tableName(), ['userId' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Вызов связи:

```
$user = User::find()->with('userItems');
```

Метод `->with('relationName')` - использует "[жадную загрузку](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record)".

Если нужны только items, то получить можно так:

```php
$user = User::findOne($id);
$items = $user->getUserItems();
```

Comment: `->all()->userItems` не будет работать, т.к. ->all() возвращает массив

Comment: @AntonRybalko, извиняюсь, поправил)